# angular-cli is not installed in ubtunu 16.04

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-cli

I have tried multiple times to install angular-cli in my ubuntu 16.04, but everytime I got failed. I am using node version 6.9.1 and npm version 3.10.8. I'm enclosing the errors here in this post.

```
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.2 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@2.0.2 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
    npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-42-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli@latest"
    npm ERR! node v6.9.1
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
    npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-e9ea1451
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! syscall rename

    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-e9ea1451' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-e9ea1451' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
    npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
    npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/pc/Downloads/node-v6.9.1/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! code 1
```

Does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1190

Try running

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
sudo npm install-g angular-cli
```

Comment: thanks man. works here as well. Still confused how it was not working for the 1st time and it can for the second. But now a new problem occurs, when i type **ng new app_name** it shows me this error _Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined_.

Comment: And does the app actually get created or does the command stop on this error?

Comment: I got that fixed. I have to use **sudo** before _ng new app_name_ . thank you nicovank.

Comment: Using sudo fixed it.